# In Oracle, find number which is larger than 80% of a set of a numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Assume I have a table with a column of integers in Oracle.  There are a good amount of rows; somewhere in the millions.  I want to write a query that gives me back an integer that is larger than 80% of all of the numbers in table.  What is the best way to approach this?

If it matters, this is Oracle 10g r1.

Comment: Does it matter if it's even higher than 80%? Because MAX(Column) could fit this definition.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be as close to 80% as possible.  81% would be acceptable but 100% would not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [PERCENTILE_DISC](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions116.htm) function if you want an actual value from the set, or [PERCENTILE_CONT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions115.htm) if you want an interpolated value for a particular percentile, say 80%:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.8) 
WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY integer_col ASC) 
FROM some_table
```

**EDIT**

If you use PERCENTILE_DISC, it will return an actual value from the dataset, so if you wanted a larger value, you'd want to increment that by 1 (for an integer column).

Comment: THat worked perfectly Ryan.  Thanks a lot.  I think I would've had to write 8000 lines of SQL to figure that out.  I really need to learn Oracle analytics someday.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the [NTILE](http://stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/functions091.htm) function to divide the input into 5 buckets, then select the MIN(Column) from the top bucket.